# Is there any low cost development board available which supports VP9 encoder at 720p30fps?

Tags: video, video-camera, embedded-systems

Hi I am searching for development board, which cost less than 150$ and also supports VP9 encoding decoding at 720p30fps.

Is there any development board available?

Comment: Plenty. Do you specifically need hardware VP9 decoding, or is software fine?

Comment: @JMY1000 I need Hardware supported  VP9 encoder or software encoder is fine. But it should support 720p30fps video streaming as well as recording.

Comment: What target bitrate?

Comment: Target bit rate is  ~1.5 Mbps.